# How to check if the Firebase user has recently signed in in a Flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I need to implement the function that a Firebase user in my app can delete his/her account if s/he wants to. Here is the account deletion function from Flutter for Firebase:

```
try {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.delete();
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'requires-recent-login') {
    print('The user must reauthenticate before this operation can be executed.');
  }
}
```

In some cases, it may happen that the user had signed in for a long time ago, which will cause the exception of 'requires-recent-login'.

Here is my actual implementation in my app:

```
  Future<String> deleteUserDataFromDatabase() async {
    try {
      // First, delete the user profile from DB
      await _firestore
          .collection('app_users')
          .doc(_auth!.currentUser!.uid)
          .delete();
  // Lastly, delete the Authentication profile
  User? user = _auth!.currentUser;
  await user!.delete();
} on Exception catch (e) {
  //print(e);
  return Future.value(e.toString());
}

return Future.value('SUCCESS');
  }
}
```

As you see, before deleting the user with the `delete()` function, I first delete the user profile data from Firestore DB. I need to do so because I set such security rules that the user itself is the only one who can delete his/her profile information in the database, not anyone else.

If the user has recently signed in, there is no problem, everything goes smoothly. But if the user has not recently signed in, then the user profile info is deleted from DB but not the **Firebase authentication user account**.

It is not an option to delete the Firebase account first, then the user profile information `_auth!.currentUser!` becomes null after running the `await user!.delete()`.

How can I overcome this problem?

In Flutter, is there a way to detect whether the Firebase user has recently signed in or not? It would be great if it was possible to detect it.

Additionally, is there a way to force user account deletion even if the user has not signed in very recently?

Comment: You could [re-authenticate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user) preemptively.

Comment: @Riwen Thanks for your comment. This complicates things quite a lot, if I interpret it right. In my app, users can create accounts either with Google Sign in, Apple Sign in, Anonymously, and with email & password as well. I assume it will require separate thinking & implementation for each of these signup solutions when I use the reauthenticate function.

Comment: Alternatively, you could move the whole logic to your back-end (cloud functions, for example). Simply call the endpoint -- which deletes the user and the document using the admin SDK --, and if the call succeeds, simply log out.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any specific time documented but it's you would have to reauthenticate when that error is thrown or even better just reauthenticate for such actions as mentioned by Riwen.

Comment: @Riwen, re-authenticate seems to be the easiest solution to the problem. Thank you for suggesting that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The exact time is determine by the server, is intentionally not documented, and can change at any time. There is no way to force deletion (or other sensitive operations) in this case, as that is intentionally trying to prevent such operations until it has confirmed the user's identity.

As others have commented, the correct flow is to try and delete the user, and then handle the error you get.

For the database flow, you have a few options:

- Mark the document as pending deletion (by writing a specific field value for that purpose), and then permanently delete it once the user account is deleted.
- Run a cleanups script periodically that either checks all documents to see if the user still exists, or only checks the ones that were marked pending deleted in the previous approach.
- Use an [`onDelete` Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_deletion) that automatically triggers on account deletion.
- Run the entire operation of deleting the document and account in a Cloud Function, which doesn't have to abide by the recency requirement (as it is a trusted environment).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is this "recently signed in" criteria valid for all types of accounts? I have anonymous signup, Apple signup, Google signup, and email&password signup options. Do I need to logout & login again all such users before trying to delete their accounts? Or, can I e.g. delete the user account of anonymous users right away if the system does not require "recently logged in" criteria for such users?

Comment: Anonymous users never entered credentials, so it makes no sense to ask them re-enter them.

Comment: What about Google signin & Apple signin users?

Comment: I'm pretty sure all other built-in providers follow the same logic of requiring a recent confirmation of the credentials, but it might be worth testing it yourself.